# PyQt scroll Area with custom widget and spacer

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I want to make a list of custom widget vertically aligned, where I dynamically add the custom widget inside a scroll Area.

[image: screenshot]

If I click on "add image", a custom widget is added to the scroll area with vertical layout.

like this :
[image]

Note that I didn't succeed to make the scroll Area expand as I add widget inside, I had to put a big minimum height to make a scrollbar appear.

The second issue is, when i add like this my widget they are spaced to much, and not added under each other. To prevent this I tried to add a vertical spacer. However, with the vertical spacer, the widget added by clicking on "add image" does not appear anymore (I use insertWidget(Vlayout.count()-1, mycustomwidget)

I organised everything like this :
[image]

the pushbutton is an example, I add my custom widget here.

Why the scroll Area doesn't expand as I had widget ? I tried :

```
self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
```

Why, when I had a spacer, the widget does not appear anymore ?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Also: why do you need to show the scroll bar if only one widget is shown (and there is unused space in the scroll area)? One of the main feature of a scroll area is that its scroll bars should only be scrollable whenever the visible space is not enough to show all the contents, which is clearly not the case in your example.

Comment: The issue is not in the code but just in the use of qt designer. 
I've solved it, I will add the solution when I have time. 
Also : as stated in the text "Note that I didn't succeed to make the scroll Area expand as I add widget inside, I had to put a big minimum height to make a scrollbar appear."  -> because in the picture I just show one widget, i add some after dynamically, The only way I was able to make it scroll when there's a lot of widget is to set a big height so that it become scrollable